# Not able to resolve TypeError: Transformer.forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, language-model

I am trying to implement the chapter 10 of NLP with transformers by lewis tunstall book. I am facing an error in this particular cell :

```
    from transformers.optimization import get_scheduler 

    from accelerate import Accelerator

    set_seed(args.seed)

   # Accelerator

    accelerator = Accelerator()
    samples_per_step = accelerator.state.num_processes * args.train_batch_size

   # Logging

    #logger, tb_writer, run_name = setup_logging(project_name.split("/")[1])
    #logger.info(accelerator.state)

    # Load model and tokenizer

    #if accelerator.is_main_process:
    #hf_repo = Repository("./", clone_from=project_name, revision=run_name)
    #model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("./", gradient_checkpointing=True)
    #tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("./")

   # Load dataset and dataloader

    dataset_name = 'transformersbook/codeparrot'
    train_dataloader, eval_dataloader = create_dataloaders(dataset_name)

   # Prepare the optimizer and learning rate scheduler

    optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(get_grouped_params(model), lr=args.learning_rate)
    lr_scheduler = get_scheduler(name=args.lr_scheduler_type, optimizer=optimizer,
                             num_warmup_steps=args.num_warmup_steps,
                             num_training_steps=args.max_train_steps,)
    def get_lr():
        return optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr']

# Prepare everything with our `accelerator` (order of args is not important)

    model, optimizer, train_dataloader, eval_dataloader = accelerator.prepare(
        model, optimizer, train_dataloader, eval_dataloader)

# Train model

    model.train()
    completed_steps = 0
    for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader, start=1):
        loss = model(batch, labels=batch).loss
        log_metrics(step, {'lr': get_lr(), 'samples': step*samples_per_step,
                           'steps': completed_steps, 'loss/train': loss.item()})
        loss = loss / args.gradient_accumulation_steps
        accelerator.backward(loss)
        if step % args.gradient_accumulation_steps == 0:
            optimizer.step()
            lr_scheduler.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            completed_steps += 1
        if step % args.save_checkpoint_steps == 0:
            logging.info('Evaluating and saving model checkpoint')
            eval_loss, perplexity = evaluate()
            log_metrics(step, {'loss/eval': eval_loss, 'perplexity': perplexity})
            accelerator.wait_for_everyone()
            unwrapped_model = accelerator.unwrap_model(model)
        
            model.train()
        if completed_steps >= args.max_train_steps:
            break

# Evaluate and save the last checkpoint

    logging.info('Evaluating and saving model after training')
    eval_loss, perplexity = evaluate()
    log_metrics(step, {'loss/eval': eval_loss, 'perplexity': perplexity})
    accelerator.wait_for_everyone()
    unwrapped_model = accelerator.unwrap_model(model)
```

Details of error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[81], line 40
     38 completed_steps = 0
     39 for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader, start=1):
---> 40     loss = model(batch, labels=batch).loss
     41     log_metrics(step, {'lr': get_lr(), 'samples': step*samples_per_step,
     42                        'steps': completed_steps, 'loss/train': loss.item()})
     43     loss = loss / args.gradient_accumulation_steps

File d:\Crimson Energy Experts\env\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []


TypeError: Transformer.forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'
```